# How to run Geb test using Groovy from command line

Tags: linux, groovy

I am trying to run a Groovy Script from the linux terminal by following this [tutorial](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#the_drive_method) on running automated tests using Geb. However I am getting this error...

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljava/util/HashMap$Entry;
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getDefaultConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:82)
    at geb.ConfigurationLoader.getConf(ConfigurationLoader.groovy:96)
    at geb.Browser.<init>(Browser.groovy:55)
    at hello.run(hello.groovy:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.HashMap$Entry
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the script I am trying to run...

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab("org.gebish:geb-core:0.10.0"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.43.1"),
    @Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.43.1")
])


import geb.Browser

def browser = new Browser();

browser.go "https://google.com/"
```

Is there another file or class I need to run a groovy script to run an automated test?

Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: what java version are you running?

Comment: @cfrick "1.8" when I run `java -version`

Comment: Could be a Groovy problem (e.g. due to Geb being compiled against an earlier Java version). Try with Java 1.7.

Comment: then what groovy version are you using?  works for me on 1.8 with groovy 2.3.9

Comment: @cfrick groovy version 1.8.6, used `sudo apt-get install groovy`

Comment: Groovy 1.8.6 is ancient (nearly 3 years old). A newer version will work fine. Maybe try http://gvmtool.net to install it for you

Comment: @Jon Kittell I am wondering if you find a solution to this issue. I am having the same problem. I've `java version "1.8.0_31"` and groovy version `Groovy Version: 2.4.0`.